# How can I turn these pdfs into MS Word templates? (w. gray background)

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2010, conversion, templates

I have two pdf files which I want to turn into MS Word templates, so that I can actually write & add data to the templates. However, I don't know how to do this, my main problem here seems to be that there is the bar on the left hand side which has a gray background, but I have no idea how I would do something like this in MS Word, to cover the full height.

I have tried to use a table for this but this does not seem ideal. I have also tried using a coloured text box, but this makes aligning things with the rest of the document very difficult.

See here for the [first pdf file](http://wikisend.com/download/607352/profile_1.pdf) and [here for the second.](http://wikisend.com/download/379586/profile_2.pdf)

Here is also an image, if you don't want to see the full pdf files:

[image]

The gray background on the left is causing troubles, and aligning the two things.

Comment: IMO: You're doing page layout, not a document... as such, this is a job for Publisher, not Word.

Comment: thanks! could I then use the Publisher layout later in MS Word? I will need to have some MS word document in the end.